# Combine: How to clean up resources while an AnyCancellable is being cancelled?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

## Overview:

- I have a async task to fetch from the database
- I have created a Future for the async task (fetching from the database).

## Question:

- How can execute custom code when the Future is cancelled?

## Purpose:

- I would like the database connection to be closed when the subscription is cancelled.

For example, I would like to use `Combine` to rewrite this helper method:

```swift
// Similar to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer/1640564-performbackgroundtask
func withDatabaseFTSContext(block: @escaping (FMDatabase?) -> Void) {
  queue.async {
    guard let database = self.database else {
      block(nil)
      return
    }

    database.open()
    let simpleTokenizer = FMSimpleTokenizer(locale: nil)
    FMDatabase.registerTokenizer(simpleTokenizer, withKey: "simple")
    database.installTokenizerModule()

    block(database)

    database.close()
  }
}
```

Could I leverage `Combine` to rewrite this method to return `FMDatabase` as a parameter of a publisher?

I was attempting to use `Combine` but it does not work. The database will be closed before `cancel()`

```swift
private func withDatabaseFTSContext() -> AnyPublisher<FMDatabase?, Never> {
  return Future<FMDatabase?, Never> { promise in
    self.queue.async {
      guard let database = self.database else {
        promise(.success(nil))
        return
      }

      database.open()
      let simpleTokenizer = FMSimpleTokenizer(locale: nil)
      FMDatabase.registerTokenizer(simpleTokenizer, withKey: "simple")
      database.installTokenizerModule()

      promise(.success(database))

      database.close() // When to close this database? Currently it will be closed before `cancel()`
    }
  }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Which to which do you want to bind?

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain what you want to do in more detail?

Comment: Could you check if you are storing `AnyCancellable` returned when subscribing to the publisher? Add breakpoints inside `withDatabaseFTSContext` and check the execution.

Comment: @user1046037 Checked. That's not the root cause. The reason is that: in the previous version without Combine, the execution is sync. In the version with Combine, after the database is returned using `promise()`, the database will be `close()` immediately.

Comment: Don't close the database inside `withDatabaseFTSContext`. Assume you are using `sink` to process the publisher's values, once you are done processing it, then you can close it in the last line of sink closure.

Comment: @user1046037 Yes! That's a good idea! I wonder can `close()` be managed automatically with `Cancellable`?

Comment: If you want to do some custom logic inside cancel, then you can probably create your own Publisher and Subscription by conforming to the respective protocols. Example: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/custom-combine-publisher/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: there isn't a callback that triggers through to the underlying Future that you can use to clean things up on a subscriber `cancel`. In the Combine design, these functions are very intentionally separated and don't have reference links back to their publishers.

(In addition, Future is a tricky figure in the Combine world because the closure is invoked immediately upon creation time, rather than when you have a subscription (if you want that, wrap in the Future publisher in a Deferred publisher)).

All that being said, what you likely want to do to solve your underlying problem is reframe how you're treating this to separate the concerns of managing the FMDB instance and publishing data. One pattern that's been reasonably useful in this context is to the make an object that holds the lifetime of the FMDB reference, and handle cleaning up resources on it's `deinit()`. You can then also have a function which vends a Publisher of whatever you need from that same object, and then the cancellation of the request is changed semantically to only cancelling getting the database, not cancelling and cleaning up the database connection.